# Ionic 3 angular 5 - can't resolve all parameter for "page"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular5

got an error **"Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object])"**  . I am trying to reach my database with angularfire - users email on toastcontroller messeges when they login. Function name : "IonViewWillLoad()"

All project : https://github.com/AndriusdevLa/test

Thats my HomePage :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';
import { ToastController } from 'toast-controller';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { User } from '../../app/modals/user';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
//public shouldReorder = false;
  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private aFAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private toastCtrl = ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController)
  {
    //this.service.getPeople().subscribe( data => {
  //    this.people = data.results
  //  });


  }


  ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.aFAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data.email && data.uid) {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'User was added successfully',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });
        toast.present();
      }

      else {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'User not found',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**I dont understand what is that error about, maby someone could tell me ? There are no more errors in IDE, only this one in browser (ionic serve).**

**App.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { StartPage } from '../pages/start/start';
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from "./app.firebase.config";
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login/login";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "angularfire2/auth";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    StartPage,
    HomePage,
    DetailPage,
    LoginPage,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    StartPage,
    HomePage,
    DetailPage,
    LoginPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClient,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},

  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**User.ts :**

```
export interface User {
  email: string;
  password: string;

}
```

**Edit :**

When I deleted - public navCtrl: NavController, from my constructor (it wasnt used, the error became smaller, but a little bit different = **?**) :

**Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: ([object Object], ?, [object Object])**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because angular can't access all the parameters required for the `HomePage`. In your constructor, you've declared four parameters angular cannot access everything except that `ToastController`. That is why the parameter in your error message is a question mark.

You have to import `ToastController` properly from `ionic-angular`, right now you are importing it from `'toast-controller'` unless you have something in that location you need to remove the line

```
import { ToastController } from 'toast-controller';
```

Then import ToastController properly from ionic-angular library.like this (change second line of your code)

```
import { NavController, ModalController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Comment: The thing is I was doing in that way and the word .create in my function was with error "Property 'create' does not exist in 'typeof ToastController', then I changed to what I showed. But now when I wrote that back again it is working.. Some weird things, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning **`toastCtrl = ToastController`**, whereas it should be  **`private toastCtrl : ToastController`**

Change

**From**

```
  constructor(private aFAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private toastCtrl = ToastController,
```

**To**

```
  constructor(private aFAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private toastCtrl : ToastController,
```

Comment: can you post your app.module.ts

Comment: added to the post app.module.ts and user.ts

Comment: please post homepage as well